# Loop over Foreach Values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a Nested array, within my JSON `$repsonse` The `ImageURI` vary from `[0]-[16]` sometimes there is 5 sometimes there is 16.

I would like to loop over `$car['Images'][0]['ImageURI'];` for example:
This is car has 4 cars and for the rest responds with a `Notice: Undefined offset:` So that when there is not 16 cars it accepts that's how many there are.

```
https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=39bcc4df-b550-e911-a2cf-00155d187d03&Rank=1&Width=960https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=39bcc4df-b550-e911-a2cf-00155d187d03&Rank=2&Width=960https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=39bcc4df-b550-e911-a2cf-00155d187d03&Rank=3&Width=960https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=39bcc4df-b550-e911-a2cf-00155d187d03&Rank=4&Width=960https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=39bcc4df-b550-e911-a2cf-00155d187d03&Rank=5&Width=960 

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 101 Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 102 Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 103 Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 104 Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 105 Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 106 Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 107 Notice: Undefined offset: 12 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 108 Notice: Undefined offset: 13 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 109 Notice: Undefined offset: 14 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 110 Notice: Undefined offset: 15 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 111 Notice: Undefined offset: 16 in /customers/8/9/9/testsite.agency/httpd.www/api/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 112 `
```

Heres my Code:

```
if(array_key_exists(0,$car['Images'])) {
                        if( isset($car['Images']) ) {
                        //it exists
                        echo    $car['Images'][0]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][1]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][2]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][3]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][4]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][5]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][6]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][7]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][8]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][9]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][10]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][11]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][12]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][13]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][14]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][15]['ImageURI'];
                        echo    $car['Images'][16]['ImageURI'];
                        echo "<br>";echo "<br>";echo "<br>";

                        }
                    }else{
                     continue;
                    }
```

Comment: So what's stopping you using a foreach?

Comment: [Did you ask this question an hour or two ago and I suggested a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770792/notice-undefined-offset-0-on-nested-array#comment101976634_57770792) - **Edit:**  Yep, 3 hours ago.

Comment: Try this: `if(count($car['Images'])>0){foreach($car['Images'] as $value{})}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop so that in can handle dynamic amounts of "Images"

This checks the "Image" `key` exists and then that it has `values` that can be looped over with `count`

```
if(array_key_exists('Images', $car) && count($car['Images'])){
    foreach($car['Images'] as $img){
        echo $img['ImageURI'];
    }
}
```

*Not tested but should work.*

Comment: Apologies guys, I didn't realize my question was a duplicate of my previous question. I appreciate all your responses I'll take a look now and see if I can get it working!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using foreach loop, here is a [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

`foreach($car['Images'] as $carImage){
    echo $carImage['ImageURI'];
}`

1. $car['Images'] - is an array you loop trough
2. $carImage - is a value of key in array
3. Edit: changed from $carImage; to $carImage['ImageURI'];

Comment: sorry my mistake, i didnt see the key ['ImageURI'], 
`echo $carImage['ImageURI'];`
 should do the work

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
foreach ($car['images'] as $c){
 echo $c['ImageURI'];
}
```

Comment: @devpro it'll probably throw an error.

Comment: Your right, i didnt add ['ImageURI']